# Why my browser does not load my projects laravel?

Tags: php, ubuntu, laravel

Use Ubuntu and installed laravel following the following tutorial

```
sudo -s
cd /var/www/ 
git clone https://github.com/laravel/laravel.git
```

[image]

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

[image]

```
cd /var/www/laravel
composer install
cd /var/www/laravel/app
chmod -R o+w storage
```

When I click

```
http://localhost/laravel/public
```

Show:

[image]

How can I fix it?

Comment: You forgot the instruction: `Use it: php composer.phar`. All you did was download a phar and move it to a directory on your server.

Comment: @MarcB If I write this in terminal just a list of commands shown

Comment: Like Simon suggested, try to use composer exactly the way it tells you to --- in current directory --- don't move it to some arbitrary folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Ubuntu 14.04 the folder is `/var/www/html`  and not `/var/www`

Answer (score 1):

First: In-order to use `composer` as STDIN alone, it must be included to your `PATH` variables otherwise, it won't be recognized as a valid command. Meaning you'll get `-bash: composer: command not found` error. Just like you would have to install `php-cli` to use `# php ...` as command.

Second thing, the `composer.phar` file should be located inside the same folder as your `composer.jason` file, which means both must be within `laravel/public/` folder so, composer can read, update the dependencies and requirements for your application.

You may follow the following steps, as I recently did without any problems.

```
    # cd /var/www
    # git clone https://github.com/laravel/laravel.git
    # mv laravel-master laravel
    # cd laravel/public/
    # curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php        
    # php composer.phar update
```

Comment: @zhelon Do you have a folder called `public_html` inside `/var/www`?

Comment: No, I dont. I have the ``html`` folder inside ``/var/www``

Comment: Ok, try it again. it is good to have html folder sometimes. @zhelon